# ElasticSearch bad regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I read up ElasticSearch's regex query documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Nowhere is it mentioned what happens if a malformed regex is passed on into the query.

So my question is , what happens if the regex is malformed ? Is an exception thrown , or an error message of some kind ?

Thanks!

Comment: try doing it, no?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Don't have access to an ES instance yet!

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch throws an exception. I added an extra `[` and ran the regex query using the Dev Tools Console in Kibana.

```
GET indexname/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "field_name": "t.[st"
        }
    }
}
```

And I get `search_phase_exception` as follows:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"regexp\" : {\n    \"field_name\" : {\n      \"value\" : \"t.[st\",\n      \"flags_value\" : 65535,\n      \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "6fy0LZRxQrOrNEFMGqL0wA",
        "index": "indexname"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "systems",
        "node": "LvCoGAkyTbiVIeyF7UtXTw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"regexp\" : {\n    \"field_name\" : {\n      \"value\" : \"t.[st\",\n      \"flags_value\" : 65535,\n      \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "6fy0LZRxQrOrNEFMGqL0wA",
          "index": "indexname",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "expected ']' at position 5"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's not really an invalid regex, it's invalid json.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a more specific exception